Is it possible to balance a top-heavy pointy object like a pyramid or cone on its point only using magnets inside the object and below it?
The closest I can find seems to be the Novium hoverpen, but the pen rests at an angle and presumably there are magnets not just below the pen. I'd think it would be possible to achieve stable balance with just magnets below and inside the object, but I've never seen anything like this.
If it's not possible, why not? I don't think Earnshaw's Theorem applies since this isn't about levitation. The point on the ground adds friction so it can help limit the movement.


That pen rests at an angle because it's stylish to do so.  I've got a pen that stands upright.

Glue $4$ magnets near the base at the center of each edge with the south pole facing down. Glue $8$ magnets to the floor with the south pole facing up, so that a pair of floor magnets is below and to each side of each pyramid magnet.
Each side is repelled, which keeps it up. The pyramid can't rotate around its point without bringing the pyramid magnets closer to floor magnets. It is held in position.
Earnshaw's Theorem doesn't apply because this is not a collection of magnets held in place solely by electrostatic or magnetostatic forces. The pyramid is not levitating. The tip of the pyramid acts like a hinge that keeps the pyramid from sliding or flipping over.

Thanks. I was thinking of something similar, but was a bit perplexed why I haven't seen anything like this in the real world. Seems like an easy effect.

Maybe because springs are an easier way if you want it to be able to move. Ropes are better if you want to hold it rigidly.

Be able to move in what way? The way I was thinking with magnets allows it to spin freely.
